# how to send an image to email in html/EJS

Tags: html, image, email, ejs, loopbackjs

I am sending an email verification trying to send the logo of the company in the html file I created to be sent. Everything works fine except the logo which is not really sended correctly.

Here is the result and the logo should be in the blue div :
[image]

this is function of sending the mail using loopback(node.js framework) :

```
 user.afterRemote('create', function (context, user, next) {

    var nom = user.nom

    var options = {
      type: 'email',
      to: user.email,
      from: senderAddress,
      subject: 'Thank you for registering',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../lib/mail.ejs'),
      redirect: 'http://localhost:3001/home',
      host: 'localhost',
      text: '\n\t{href}',
      nom: nom,
      body: 'Veuillez vérifier votre email, en cliquant sur ce lien :',
      port: '3000',
      user: user
    };

    user.verify(options, function (err, response) {
      context.res.render('response', {
        title: 'Signed up successfully',
        content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link before logging in.',
        redirectTo: '/',
        redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
      });
    });
  });
```

and this is my html where to insert the image :

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" class="textContent">
      <img src="../public/images/logo-casting.png" width="210" class="flexibleImage" alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display:block" />
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are adding the src "../public/images/logo-casting.png", html knows that url when the html is inside that server/space but not in the email of someone, you should upload that image somewhere and use that entire link

Comment: i uploaded the image in a website and the used the link but nothing happened still the same problem. Here's my update :                                                                         `<img src="https://www.imgur.com/a/r8Vqkz4" width="210" class="flexibleImage" alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display:block" />`

Comment: again thats not a valid address, you are trying to point to an image, see the url you sent, it doesnt have any .png .jpg etc. for that link that you posted the correct url you should add is "//i.imgur.com/CjEAaoP.jpg"

Comment: to get that direction, in the page you sent just do right click and select "copy image link" (or you can check the html and see the src there bu that seems like the long road)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly take image from your own project directory path. because you are sending http. So upload your image to a website and paste the url.